# SQLAlchemy ORM with dynamic table schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to task **SQLAlchemy ORM** to create class `Field` that describes all fields in my database:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Field(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fields'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'SCM'}
    id = Column(String(20), primary_key=True)
```

The issue is that table `fields` describes different fields in different schemas, i.e.

```
SCM.fields
TDN.fields
...
```

I need class Field to

- Be initialized with object `fieldset` before records can be read from db
- Schema determined by `fieldset.get_schema()` before table `<schema>.fields` is read.

Something like this:

session.query(Field(fieldset))).filter(Field.id=='some field')

However, adding

```
def __init__(self, fieldset)
    pass
```

to `class Field` results in

> `__init__() takes 1 positional argument...`

- I could lump all `fields` tables into one schema and add column 'schema_name' but I still need Field have link to its fieldset.

Can this be done using **SQLAlchemy ORM** or should I switch to **SqlAlchemy Core** where I would have more control over object instantiation?

Comment: Do the tables called `fields` already exist per schema? Could you work with reflection?

Comment: What I mean is I'd approach this a bit differently: reflect the `fields` tables from the schemas separately to a dictionary, where the schema is the key.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä ``fields`` already exist. It looks like reflection is part of SQLAlchemy Core. I am trying to deploy SQLAlchemy in place of my "DIY" library. Do you suggest I go with Core, or use Core to create reflection and go with ORM?

Comment: There's automapper as well, if you wish to reflect as declarative classes (orm).

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Looks like reflection/automapper is when database determines metadata, which would be bad for me. I will probably create a common table with "schema_name" column instead.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is solvable and the solution is documented as [Augmenting the Base](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#augmenting-the-base)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr, declarative_base

class Field:
    __tablename__ = 'fields'

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        # schema will be part of class name, which works for me
        # Example: class FieldSCM --> Field with schema SCM
        return dict(schema=cls.__name__[5:].upper())

    id = Column(String(20), primary_key=True)

Field = declarative_base(cls=Field)


class FieldSet:
    def __init__(self, schema):
        self.fieldtype  = type('Field' + schema.upper(), (Field,), {})
```

Proof of concept:

```
FieldSet('ork').fieldtype.__table__
```

> Table('fields', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', String(length=20), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False), schema='ORK')